# unable to open my eclipse due to java error

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using my eclipse in very well and fine condition before few days. after that, I tried to work on Netbeans IDE, but I configured the Java JRE separately and tried to work with maven with Netbeans. but since the day I added the JRE path value and started using Netbeans I'm completely unable to open my Eclipse.
**Java was started but returned exit code = 1**

this error is prompt after trying to open it.
Help...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEkIj.png)

Comment: what is version of java  installed in your system? the `eclipse.exe` you running requires `java 11`

Comment: looks like its an error about java version. it require version `java 11 `

Comment: It looks like you try to run Eclipse with a 32-bit Java, but a 64-bit Java is required. Better install a current Eclipse with an embedded Java.

Answer (score 0):

Inside eclipse folder open the file eclipse.ini in notepad or notepad++ you can find required java version mentioned like

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1
```

and add the following as last line. Before this, you have to close Eclipse (you can add your preferred jdk version).

```
-vm
Path-to-java11\bin\javaw.exe
```

Note there is linebreak between `-vm` and `path` After making changes, you can start eclipse. For more details, refer this link. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini